# strange outline in vim only on css properties with the letter "p"

Tags: css, vim, terminal

vim is showing a strange outline on the space character and a following lowercase p. 
[image: strange highlight on p]

I have done a few tests, it's not only affecting p characters after a semicolon, the following line of code displays this bug as well:

```
/* a perfectly executed plan */
```

Both of the `p` characters and the spaces before them are affected by this weird bug.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.3 using Terminal Version 2.3 (309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be search highlighting if the last search you did with forward slash (<kbd>/</kbd>) was `/ p`. Try searching for something else or disabling search highlighting:

```
:set nohlsearch
```

Comment: This is indeed what's happening.  If you do want to have hlsearch (I like it) but want to be able to clear the search highlighting, you can do so with `:let @/=""`.  I have actually bound that to `:C` in my .vimrc, with `command! C let @/=""`.

Comment: Riley: That functionality's in the built-in `:noh[lsearch]` command.